# Establecer un Width a las columnas del JTable en Java

Tags: java

Me gustaría anchar mas las columnas del JTable porque la información presentada se ve muy pegada y no se muestra completa, hay que ajustarlo manualmente para poder visualizar todo el contenido.

Si yo estuviera usando `model.addColumn("Nombre");`, yo podría usar `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(30);` pero, no hago uso de esto.

Código de mi JTable:

```
// Estableciendo el título de las columnas del JTable
String[] columnas = {"#", "Tipo", "Franja", "Origen", "Destino", "Duracion", "Precio"};

// Creando un DefaultTableModel
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null, columnas);

// Creando el JTable y asignandole el DefaultTableModel
JTable table = new JTable(model);

// Agregar filas al JTable leyendo la base de datos
String showTableSQL = "SELECT * FROM llamadas";
Connection conn = null;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Object[][] filas = null;

                        try {
                            conexion = new ConexionBD();
                            conn = conexion.getConnection();
                            st = conn.createStatement();
                            rs = st.executeQuery(showTableSQL);

                            int numColumnas = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); // Saber la cantidad de columnas que existen
                            int numFilas = 0;
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                numFilas++;
                            }
                            filas = new Object[numFilas][numColumnas];
                            rs.beforeFirst();

                            int contadorTmp = 0;
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                filas[contadorTmp][0] = Integer.toString(rs.getInt(1));     // ID
                                filas[contadorTmp][1] = rs.getString(2);
                                filas[contadorTmp][2] = rs.getString(3);
                                filas[contadorTmp][3] = String.valueOf(rs.getString(4)).replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "($1) $2-$3");
                                filas[contadorTmp][4] = String.valueOf(rs.getString(5)).replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "($1) $2-$3");
                                filas[contadorTmp][5] = Integer.toString(rs.getInt(6));
                                filas[contadorTmp][6] = Double.toString(rs.getDouble(7));
                                contadorTmp++;
                            }

                        } catch (SQLException errorSQL) { errorSQL.printStackTrace(); }
                            finally { 
                                try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (Exception errorRS) { errorRS.printStackTrace(); }
                                try { if (st != null) st.close(); } catch (Exception errorST) { errorST.printStackTrace(); }
                                try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (Exception errorCONN) { errorCONN.printStackTrace(); }
                            }

                        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(filas, columnas);
                        table.setModel(model);
```

He tratado de investigar una forma de establecer un Width a cada columna en este caso pero, no encuentro nada.

Cualquier ayuda será bien recibida.

Comment: ya intentaste usar `setPreferredWidth`

Comment: Aunque no tenga que ver con tu pregunta. ten cuidado porque has declarado he instanciado dos veces `model`. La primera vez no sirve para nada. Supongo que no es el código que vas a compilar.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n tienes razón, es un detalle que se me ha pasado, gracias por dejármelo saber. He cambiado la ultima instancia a esta línea: model = new DefaultTableModel(filas, columnas);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Búscalo por su identificador. Por ejemplo para la segunda columna llamada Tipo sería:

```
table.getColumn("Tipo").setPreferredWidth(30);
```

Este método usa `equals` para ver si coincide con algún identificador, [según la documentación de java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getColumn(java.lang.Object)), pasado en el objeto `columnas`.

Comment: ha funcionado pero, tengo un problemita. He agregado esa línea antes de llenar el JTable. Al arrancar el programa, las columnas tienen el width correcto pero, una vez ingresas datos y el JTable se llena, las columnas regresan a su estado original, todas pegadas. Debo establecer el width entonces adentro del codigo de llenar el JTable?, el fin es que siempre se quede con un width, para que se vea bonito.

Comment: Si, debes de hacerlo al final. Porque si vuelves a instanciar la tabla se llena de nuevo las listas internas que usan. Aunque uses la misma variable de columnas no es lo mismo, es un objeto JTable nuevo. Lo que puedes hacer luego es añadir y quitar filas, pero no instanciarlo de nuevo. Tambien puedes hacerte un método que dé el formato que quieres a la tabla, no sólo el ancho, si no los renders, etc... y llamarlo cuando lo necesites.

Comment: a ver estoy confundido, la tabla solo la instacio y la creo al comienzo de todo el programa de forma global, lo unico que hago uso por segunda vez es el: model = new DefaultTableModel(filas, columnas);, se me hace raro que el width no se quede para siempre al establecerlos antes de llenar el jtable

Comment: Eso que tú dices que sólo llamas a `new` es instanciar y **cada vez que lo hagas creas un objeto nuevo** que lo asignas a tu varible `model`. Lo que dices que haces al principio de manera global se llama **declarar** no instanciar (ejemplo `DefaultTableModel model;`).

Comment: ah vale, cierto, lo he confundido. Entonces, en este caso: 1. deseo que al iniciar el programa las columnas tengan un width para que tengan buena apariencia. 2. al llenar el jtable el width debe mantenerse. Para resolver estas dos cosas, establezco el width antes de llenar el jtable y despues, cierto?, me ha funcionado de esta manera pero, siento que es poco eficiente, o no sería la mejor forma. Por cierto, gracias por tratar de ayudarme y por todo tu tiempo, te lo agradezco.

Comment: Sólo le tienes que dar formato después

Answer (score 0):

Seria usar el metodo `setPreferredWidth()`

Una forma seria

```
TableColumn columna = null;
//se hace el recorrido de tu arreglo de columnas
for (int i = 0; i < columna.length; i++) {
    columna = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
    swith(i){
        case 0:
            columna.setPreferredWidth(50); //el ancho de la column
            break;
        case 1:
            columna.setPreferredWidth(80);
            break;
        //etc aqui las demas columnas
    }

}
```